# I opened up Remote Desktop in Azure and now I can't do a VIP swap

Tags: azure

..without enabling Remote Desktop *every* time.

I used the Azure Management portal to setup Remote Desktop for Production, but I can't find an option to remove it again. Because you can't do any VIP swaps if the endpoints are not the same, I am doomed to enable Remote Desktop forever!!

Help :(

Answer (score 0):

To disable the RDP, I will set the remote desktop account expiry date to past. You can configure it using management portal itself.